# Event Handling with Function Literals

Tags: javascript

So I've been going through Head First JavaScript and I came to a section on Event Handling with Function Literals. The book explains that you can wire all your event handling in your 'script' tags. But I am confused on how I get multiple functions to fire off on one event. Here's my code:

```
//Event Handling with Function Literals
  window.onload = function(evt) {

//THIS IS BROKEN
    document.body.onresize = resizeImg();reportImgHeight();

//Onload: Functions to Execute -- THESE WORK    
    resizeImg();
    reportImgHeight();
  }
```

So specifically for this example, how do I get an "onresize" event to execute BOTH *resizeImg* and *reportImgHeight* (functions which I have defined elsewhere in my code). Thank you!

Comment: I think you should look around for a better, at least newer, book. That book is five years old.

Comment: Well people say good things about "JavaScript: The Good Parts" and "Secrets Of the JavaScript Ninja". I learned JavaScript when there weren't any good books (besides the venerable O'Reilly book, which is more of a reference than a tutorial) so I missed out on the benefits of a good tutorial. There are also many great on-line resources (like this place!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do this

```
document.body.onresize = function(){
    resizeImg();
    reportImgHeight();
};
```

And if you want to call them like they would be if they were separate you could do something like this

```
document.body.onresize = function(){
    resizeImg.apply(this, arguments);
    reportImgHeight.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

This passes through the `this` that you would have had if it were one, and the arguments passes through all of the arguments that were passed to the event.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest solution is to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) :

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeImg);
window.addEventListener('resize', reportImgHeight);
```

This way you can decouple both bindings.

Note also that you should bind the `resize` event to the window, not to a document part.

Comment: Note that order of execution is not guaranteed here so `reportImageHeight` might report an incorrect result. Still +1 for correct listener approach.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The execution order is guaranteed : http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-phase

Comment: `this must be the list of all event listeners that have been registered on the current target in their order of registration. ... Finally, the implementation must process all candidate event handlers in order` Today I learned.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Your error might have come from the fact that in the first versions of the DOM specification the order wasn't guaranteed.